# java tutorial - unknown host exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a URL using the tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);

        in.close();
    }

}
```

But I'm getting below exception. www.google.com is a known host ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:234)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:307)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:324)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at URLReader.main(URLReader.java:8)
```

Comment: "google" URL does not like to be referred by name "oracle" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running behind a proxy ? 
The article seems to suggest there is a configuration needed in that case.

> Alternatively, the program might hang or you might see an exception stack trace. If either of the latter two events occurs, you may have to set the proxy host so that the program can find the Oracle server.

Answer (score 3):

Are you behind a proxy? Try to set the proxy in eclipse or try

```
 java -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=10.0.0.14 -DproxyPort=6588 JavApp
```

Answer (score 2):

I think its network error check your internet Connection....

Comment: It would fit better as a comment TMHO. for the asker: try running the same code with another web-site, do you still get teh same error ?